# Gmail not accepting <style> and @import css methods

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create an email template but after several tests, and reading https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ I found that Gmail does not support `<style></style>` tags or the `@import` element in CSS.

The font I indent to use in my email is `"Gotham Rounded A"` which is not a publicly available font which is why I was trying to use the `@import url()` in my CSS to get the font into the email.

Does anyone know a solution **that would** allow me to use this font in the email template?

Comment: If im correct gmail doesnt accept custom style...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Web Fonts support is increasing between the email clients, but you are not lucky with Gmail. As you can read in Campaign Monitor, Gmail will not allow you to show custom fonts. (Probably neither any other web-based client):
https://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/will-it-work/webfonts/

If the use of custom font is mandatory you will need to use images.

**Edited:**

You can try to use it and get fallback in another one, for example 'Times New Roman':

```
<style>
    @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merienda);
   /* All your usual CSS here */
   h4 {
       font-family: Merienda, 'Times New Roman', serif;
       color: #444444;
       font-size: 24px;
   } 
</style>
```

But probably inlining your CSS before sending will give you more cross-compatibilty: http://inliner.cm/

Comment: Thanks for your input. Do you know if there is a way to create a fall-back type font so that it falls back to a web safe font if it is not able to load my custom one?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the only way you can reliably include a custom font in emails is by using an image. If you need dynamically generated text, you can always create an image dynamically, for example: `<img src="http://example.com/generate-image/?msg=Sample+Message+Text" />`. That will require generating images programmatically with PHP or ASP.